# OpenEXR Render Error when running in new process

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to render some images using the Blender Python module, **in a new process** (but never more than 1 process at a time).

I am able to create JPEG/PNG/OpenEXR renderings without spawning a new process.

However, I am only able to create JPEG/PNG renderings while spawning a new process. **There is an error when generating in OpenEXR format.**

Minimum code example below:

```
import bpy
from multiprocessing import Pool

def blender_test_render():
    bpy.context.scene.render.engine = "CYCLES"
    bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = 1
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x, bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 300, 300
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "output"

    for fmt in ("JPEG", "PNG", "OPEN_EXR"):
        print(f"generating {fmt}")
        bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = fmt
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
    return "abc123"

def run_as_process(func):
    p = Pool(processes=1)
    x = p.apply_async(func)
    ret = x.get()
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return ret

retval = blender_test_render()  # works
print(f"success: {retval}")

retval = run_as_process(blender_test_render)  # fails on OPEN_EXR format
print(f"success: {retval}")
```

Error:

```
IMB_exr_begin_write: ERROR: No such file or directory.
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/mnt/c/test_dir/test_code.py", line 164, in __main__
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/2.92/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Error writing render result, No such file or directory (see console)
Error: Render error (No such file or directory) cannot save: '/mnt/c/test_dir/output.exr'
```

Of course, the directory exists:

```
$ cat /mnt/c/test_dir/
cat: /mnt/c/test_dir/: Is a directory
```

Comment: It's an OS specific problem, I suspect.  what does `ls -al /mnt/c/test_dir` show?

Comment: `-rwxrwxrwx` for `test_code.py` and all the `output.{ext}`, `drwxrwxrwx` for `.` and `..`. I'm using WSL Ubuntu locally but I have the same error on a remote Debian server.

Comment: I'm at a lost.  I was guessing that output.exr was owned by some other user or group and didn't have the right write bits set but that should work.